# How do I get a page to resize without element to change

Tags: html, css, web, resize

When open my page on mobile the screen look different.
I am trying to create timeline page but for some how when I change the  screen size the timeline also change.

Why?

Please see attached the different between mobile and desktop page.
[Fit to screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jXq0.jpg)

CSS:

```css
.container-style {
  max-width: 1300px;
  max-height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #a0a0a0;
}

.timeline ul {
  padding: 1em 0 0 2em;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.timeline ul::before {
  content: ' ';
  height: 100%;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 24%;
  display: block;
}

.timeline li div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.timeline .bullet {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #F93B69;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 110px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.timeline .time {
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 2.0em;
  margin-top: 120px;
  color: #F93B69;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}

.timeline .desc {
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: .90em;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-style">
  <div class="timeline">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="time">Overview</div>
        <div class="bullet pink"></div>
        <div class="desc">
          <p><span style="color: #F93B69;font-weight:bold">FOR ALL GENERATIONS</span>, We have created .</p>
        </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I resize my browser website doesn't resize. Do anyone know what logic to approach to make this fit all screens also with mobile

Comment: Can you please use Stackoverflow preview editor to make a minimal reuseable example? I dont want to read that HTML from the comment ...

Comment: But try to set position absolute left 50% and transform translateX -50% to the bullet. And give the timeline a position relative

Comment: Thanks your solution work